# Datatables columnFilter whole word

Tags: jquery, filter, filtering, datatables

Is there way to filter just whole word match data with columnFilter plugin for datatables?

For exampple if I have following data in column:
N, NEW

when select N filter, to display only rows that contain N values, not NEW.